# How I can show different name for one app? I want show name of application in Iphone and in App

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

For example, in iPhone device I want show application name as "App Name", but on AppStore "App Name: very nice app". How I can do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Device** Whatever name you want to show on the device, you can put it inside `Info.plist` file as `Bundle display name` shown below,

[image]

**AppStore** Whatever name you want to show on AppStore, you can put it on itunesConnect in `App Information` section as shown,

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can set the name that appears in the app store in the **App Name** field on iTunes Connect. You can change the name whenever you upload a new version.